# SQL QUERY for grouping records together based on first word (text) in a column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to present records from a table in such a way that they are grouped and counted based on the first word (text) in a column.

My SQL Server table looks like this:

```
BinID   BinName
2070     (for item PMI-67281)
3078    1 (for item PMI-14233)
2914    1 (for item PMI-1600537)
5272    1702 (for item 004908A)
5004    1702 (for item 0332002225BLK)
4019    1702 (for item 0332204204)
1208    1A1 (for item BWB2)
1662    1A1 (for item BWB27)
1212    1A1 (for item BWB31)
1213    1A1 (for item BWB35-S)
2583    1A2 (for item BWBT359)
1234    1A2 (for item BWBT364)
1266    1A3 (for item BWB1438)
2418    1A5 (for item 1006101)
2008    1A5 (for item 107794X)
1281    1ATOP (for item BWPA3493)
1218    1B1 (for item BWB161-S)
```

My required result is as below:

```
BinID   BinName Count
5272    1702 (for item 004908A) 
5004    1702 (for item 0332002225BLK)   
4019    1702 (for item 0332204204)  3
1208    1A1 (for item BWB2) 
1662    1A1 (for item BWB27)    
1212    1A1 (for item BWB31)    
1213    1A1 (for item BWB35-S)  4
2583    1A2 (for item BWBT359)  
1234    1A2 (for item BWBT364)  2
1266    1A3 (for item BWB1438)  1
2418    1A5 (for item 1006101)  
2008    1A5 (for item 107794X)  2
1281    1ATOP (for item BWPA3493)   1
1218    1B1 (for item BWB161-S) 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the LEFT and CHARINDEX functions - use it to find the first space, and order by it, or group on it, or whatever you wish to do.

```
SELECT    BinID
         ,BinName
FROM      TABLE
ORDER BY  LEFT(BinName,CHARINDEX(' ', BinName)-1)
```